# Convert date string to timestamp with timezone in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a date string `2020-10-14, 14:13:23`, I want to convert this to `timestamp with timezone` format in **python** so that I can delete the rows with this particular timestamp in my postgresql table

[image]

Please suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to `cast`?

```
select '2020-10-14, 14:13:23'::timestamp with time zone
```

```
| timestamptz            |
| :--------------------- |
| 2020-10-14 14:13:23+01 |
```

If you want to filter on timestamps that belong to the same second as this literal value:

```
select *
from mytable
where execution_date >= '2020-10-14, 14:13:23'::timestamp with time zone
  and execution_date <  '2020-10-14, 14:13:23'::timestamp with time zone + interval '1 second'
```

Comment: I did `select '2020-10-14, 14:13:23'::timestamp with time zone from table_name` and I got 16 rows but in actual the table contains only two rows with this timestamp. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mahesh: please provide sample data and desired results. Better yet, are you able to set up a https://dbfiddle.uk/ that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: hey, I am unable to provide sample data in the fiddle never used it.. but what I am trying to do is fetch all the rows with this timestamp. so i wrote the query `select * from table_name where execution_date in (select '2020-10-14, 14:13:23'::timestamp with time zone)` but it is returning **0 rows**. `execution_date` is the column name as shown in the above image

Comment: @Mahesh: your data has fractional seconds, not the value that you are passing. So there is no exact match.